# This sentence is Past Simple or Participle "The sheep all baaed in unison."?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, sentence, past-tense, past-participles

This sentence **"The sheep all baaed in unison."** is Past Simple or Participle?

And could give me somes examples of Past Simple and Participle using the word **"baaed"**.

Comment: Why do you think it couldn't be both?

Comment: If "baaed" were a participle, it would be a passive participle, so "baa" would have to be a transitive verb. I can (just barely) imagine that, with the direct object of "baa" being the sound produced by the baaing sheep. So here's a participle example for you: The song, though baaed by a flock of sheep, greatly resembled my own singing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verb form *baaed* serves both as a **simple** and as a **participle**.

As for examples, your sentence **"The sheep all baaed in unison."** is in the *simple aspect.*

An example of the *participle* could be, **"The sheep had all baaed in unison."**